# My GMAIL Has Been Deleted

Tags: gmail

All gmails from june of 2018 have been deleted.  Everything is gone.  It was fine the last time I signed in.  How can you recover my messages.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the trash folder in Gmail? If not, you can type `in:trash` in the search box and press enter.

If your emails are there, you can:

1. Select one or more of the emails
2. Right-click on any one of the selected emails
3. Go to 'Move to' > Inbox (or any other folder that you want)